# Find/replace underscored words to camelCase words using regex?

Tags: vim, regex, sed

I have a ton of text files that are tagged with underscore-connected words like @some_text, but I would like to convert those to tags in camel case, like @someText. How can I use regex (either in vim or with sed or similar tool) to find and replace these?

Comment: [Converting variables to or from camel case - Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_variables_to_or_from_camel_case)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU sed, you could do `s=_\([A-Za-z]\)=\u\1=g`.